# ¿Cómo contar cantidad total de id duplicados?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estimados: tengo la siguiente función en sql server:

```
SELECT id, count(*)
FROM tabla
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Pero devuelve los grupos de duplicados, y yo lo que pretendo es la cantidad de duplicados (solo el número de la suma de los registros) cuyo id se encuentra en más de un registro.

Ejemplo:  '23' registros duplicados

Comment: ¿El número de la suma de los registros o la suma del número de registros?

Answer (score 5):

Simplemente agrega un nuevo `SELECT COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Duplicados
FROM (
      SELECT id, COUNT(*) N
      FROM tabla
      GROUP BY id
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t;
```